# How to correctly release a CGMutablePathRef in -dealloc?

Tags: ios, memory-management, core-graphics, core-foundation

Problem: Maybe the `CGMutablePathRef` has been created and set, but maybe not.

What I do right now in `-dealloc` is:

```
if (path != NULL) {
    CGPathRelease(path);
    path = NULL;
}
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html),

> void CGPathRelease (
>      CGPathRef path
>   );
>
> This function is equivalent to CFRelease, except that it does not cause an error if the path parameter is NULL.

So there is no need to NULL check.

Comment: Thanks! Good answer.